# Login to Bluemix VM suddenly asks for password

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I have created a VM with a public ssh key.
Once is it created, I am able to login with the private ssh key:

```
ssh -i cloud.key ibmcloud@129.41.xxx.xx
```

After some successful logins, suddenly when trying to login with the same command I am asked for a password:

```
$ ssh -i cloud.key ibmcloud@129.41.xxx.xx
ibmcloud@129.41.133.80's password:
```

Do you know why is this happening?
I have removed and recreated the VM with same behaviour. After some successful logins, it started to ask for a password.

[EDITED] Added -vv verbose info:

```
.........
.........
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 12:05:44:27:ab:c9:98:5f:45:ab:1d:d7:e0:ca:ba:3a
debug1: Host '129.41.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: cloud.key (0x6000686e0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: cloud.key
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question....  the issue was a colleague changed home directory permissions to 777 and for some reason SSH thinks that is not secure and doesn't authenticate although -vv parameter doesn't say anything about it.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: i cant access bluemix vm,why!due to my free trial account how you are accessing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no typos in your command . For example a typo in the IP address can inadvertently point you to another VM where your key would not work and it would fallback to using a password.    If that's not the case then your best bet is to get more details about why you're being prompted for a password. Try the following command:

```
$ ssh -vv -i cloud.key ibmcloud@129.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The will give a detailed trace of the command  as it's negotiating with  your VM  and give you some indication of why it's bypassing your keyfile and falling back to using a password instead. If the cause of the behavior  is still not clear after you try this,  post the output of the command above.

Comment: Sorry for the delay answering, I was out of office. I update the question with -vv output. Honestly, I don't see any error or tip about why login using private key is not working. Do you have any suggestion reading the output? Thanks!

Comment: I've seen that debug log pattern when the public key part of the key pair is not on the server at all or the ssh daemon server config is not pointing to the `authorized_keys` file that has the public key. Did you generate the keys yourself or did you use the ones that werer generated by the Web UI when you created the image ?

Comment: I created myself. And as I said it worked fine for a while. Currently investigating if the issue could be a permission change a colleague did on the home directory although the -vv doesn't say anything about it. I will come back.

Comment: Confirmed. The issue was a colleague changed home directory permissions to 777 and for some reason SSH thinks that is not secure and doesn't authenticate although -vv parameter doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: It must be a ssh client issue - you should get an error even without the -vv flag  if the private key file has 777 permissions. On MAC OS X Yosemite it's a very prominent message that says  **WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE ! ... This private key file will be ignored**

Comment: It was not private key locally, but public key remotely. When I referred to home directory permissions was referring to remote box.

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh ibmcloud@129.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

That should work. If it doesn't, [generate a new ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/), copy it to clipboard with xclip or pbcopy, then paste it in Bluemix (Create a VM > new SSH key > Import > paste ssh key).